# Error starting node server

Tags: node.js

I get the following error when trying to start a node server. It looks like it is related to combohandler that was installed using node package manager (npm).

Can anyone help please?

```
TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'error'
    at /Repository/combo/node_modules/combohandler/lib/server.js:23:9
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Repository/combo/server.js:8:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

Below you can see the version of express I am using:

```
Brendans-MacBook-Pro:combo brendan_rice$ npm view express version
npm WARN express@1.0.4 package.json: 'modules' object is deprecated
npm WARN express@1.0.5 package.json: 'modules' object is deprecated
npm WARN express@1.0.6 package.json: 'modules' object is deprecated
npm WARN express@1.0.7 package.json: 'modules' object is deprecated
3.0.0rc1
```

Comment: Are you using the express module? Which version?

Comment: Yea I am using express, I have put the details in the main post. What you thinking Marc? Exress version conflict?

Comment: yes, express version conflict, see answer of penartur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combohandler` does not support `express` v3.0.0: https://github.com/rgrove/combohandler/blob/master/package.json

You could probably workaround the error by not creating an `express` server manually but rather by letting `combohandler` to take care of it. That is, do not pass the second argument to the `combohandler` constructor.

Comment: Thanks penartur, that was exactly the problem, I installed an earlier version of express and it worked.